# How can I combine "xticlabel" and "with labels" in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
"A" 1306051 "hello"
"B" 1384727 "world"
```

I use this command to plot the data:

```
plot 'data_file' using (column(0)):2:xticlabel(1)
```

I'd like to label (some of) the data points with the "with labels"-option using the values from the last column, but I do not know how to do this in my case where I am already using "xticlabel". All examples I have found did not include xticlabel and I do not see a straight forward way to combine "xticlabel" and "with labels".

Comment: ok, one workaround can be to plot the same data twice, once with xticlabel and once with "with labels"... but that would not be a nice solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me to use

```
plot 'data.dat' using (column(0)):2:3:xticlabel(1) with labels
```

with your data, which gives this plot:

[image]

If you only want to label some of the points like this, though, you might have to just plot twice (possibly using the `offset` option to `with labels` so the labels are not on top of the points being plotted).

Comment: thanks! I only tried (column(0)):2:xticlabel(1):3 and that did not work... this solution works, but I loose the data points themselves, so I probably really have to plot twice...